# load data only when slide down with jquery

Tags: jquery, load, slidedown

I have a link that when user clicks on it some data loaded into a `div`. I want to display waiting message to user until the data fetch completely from server and then show it to user.

I also want to call the data `url` happen only when the result box is going down(slide down) not in both of slide down and slide up events to reduce load on server.

my code is here but i don't know how implement second part into it:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $("#prereq").hide();
        $("#prereqlink").click(function() {
             $("#prereq").html("please wait ...");
             $("#prereq").slideToggle("slow");

             $.ajax({ url:"referee.php",
                      success:function(data) {
                              $("#prereq").html(data);
                    }
             });

        });
 });
```

would you help me??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a way.by using   $("#prereq").is(":visible")  we can check it.

Comment: ah! great. I forgot about that. So, there is no need to check class or variable to see if slide is up/down.

Answer (score 2):

try something like this but **please note that I am not so sure**

```
var mode = 'down';

$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#prereq").hide();
    $("#prereqlink").click(function() {
         $("#prereq").html("please wait ...");
         $("#prereq").slideToggle("slow");
    if(mode == 'down'){
         $.ajax({ url:"referee.php",
                  success:function(data) {
                        mode = 'up';
                          $("#prereq").html(data);
                }
         });
    }
    else{
        mode = 'down';
    }

    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#prereq").hide();
    /* OR to add class to initialize as required 
     $("#prereq").addClass(("downMode").hide(); 
    */
    $("#prereqlink").click(function() {
         $("#prereq").slideToggle("slow", function(){
             $.ajax({ url:"referee.php",
                  beforeSend: function() {
                   if ($("#prereq").hasClass("downMode")){
                     $("#prereq").html("please wait ...").show();   
                     return true;
                   }
                   /* cancel ajax request */
                   return false ;   
                  },
                  success:function(data) {
                   $("#prereq").html(data);
                  }
             });
        }).toggleClass("downMode");
    });
 });
```

Edit:
I think we can remove beforeSend and check for class before the $.ajax(...) in slideToggle callback as
 `if ($(this).is('.downMode')){ $.ajax(....`